# jQuery(selector) or $(selector), which one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Which is better way to use `jQuery()`? I've heard that `jQuery(element)` doesn't ruin code in e.g. Wordpress. But `$` is easier and faster to write.

Which one do you prefer and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My order of preference is `$()`, then `var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(); $jq()`, then finally `jQuery()`.  You can also limit the scope of the `$` function by doing:

```
;(function($){
    ...in here $ means jQuery...
})(jQuery);
```

That is create an anonymous function with a parameter of `$`, pass in jQuery as the parameter and within the function the parameter scope overrides any globally scoped `$` function. The latter is most useful when creating plugins yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It just depends on what you need to do, they're both identical.

If you're using another library like Prototype (which also uses $), you'll need to us jQuery, but in most cases where there is no clash, just use $()

Comment: Thanks for both answers, this one was a bit faster, though :-D

Answer (score 2):

The $ shorthand is also used by other frameworks (like prototype), so if you're not using that, feel free to use $ for shorthand.  The two are just aliases of each other as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For your own extensions that use `$` only to call `jQuery`, you can also use the standard trick of wrapping your code like this

```
(function($) {
   ... your other code using $(selector).moo here ....
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of my jQuery code falls into two categories: plugins and on-page-load stuff.

For plugins, here's the easiest way:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myplugin = function() { ... };
})(jQuery);
```

For on-page-load stuff, which is most of it, just do this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('a[href$="foo"]').click( ... );
});
```

This way, it doesn't matter at all if there's extra libraries included (eg: Prototype), and you can still use $ instead of typing out "jQuery" each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var jq=jQuery.noConflict();` to deal with name conflicts.

Ex:

```
var $jq=jQuery.noConflict();
$jq("p").hide();
```